# How to constrain a type to be literal meaning that the user must write "as const"

Tags: typescript

I want to define a literal type that all users must write 'as const'

```
type foo= literalType //
const num0:foo = 123 // error
const num:foo = <const>123 //ok
const str:foo = 'str' as const //ok
const arr:foo = [1,2,3] as const //ok 
const obj:foo = {name:'lili'} // error
const obj1:foo = {name:'lili'} as cosnt // ok
//...
```

demo2
Constrain generics to be literals ,T in foo .

```
function foo<T>( obj:{literal:T} ){}
foo({
literal: <const>123 //ok
})
foo0({
literal: [1,2,3] //error Because it's not literal
})
foo1({
literal: <const> [1,2,3] //ok
})
foo2({
literal: <const> {name:'li'} //ok
})
foo3({
literal: {name:'li'} //error Because it's not literal
})
```

How to do in TS ?

After writing a component, a document is returned.  The user will see the default value, which should be literal

[image]

Like this

[image]

not [image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: I now have to say to everyone I meet that when you write a custom component, the default value must be 'as const'.  I'm trying to find a better way

Comment: What is the reason you need 123 in the type? Surely a default value won't have to be passed multiple times, so you wouldn't need to check at compile time that the same default value is being passed each time the type is used.

Comment: Components may require incoming type for joint type Such as' aaa '|' BBB 'I need to tell others the default' aaa ',

Comment: @missannil Maybe I don't understand something, but since you have provided literal object as an argument, TS is able to infer every nested key and  value. Please see my article about inference https://catchts.com/infer-arguments . Here https://tsplay.dev/w8KL9W you can find your example with infered object properties

Comment: @ captain-yossarian
Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @missannil if it works for you I can turn it to the answer with more explanation.